# Don't use later library version from transitive dependency in Gradle

Tags: gradle, dependencies, build.gradle, transitive-dependency

in my Android project I use

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.2.0'
```

I need okhttp in version 2.2.0 for my code to work properly. But I have a problem when I add

```
compile('io.intercom.android:intercom-sdk:1.1.2@aar') {
        transitive = true
}
```

Because inside intercom-sdk there is okhttp dependency again for later version:

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
```

Which results that my code uses that later version 2.4.0 instead of 2.2.0 I want. Is there please any way how in my module I can use 2.2.0 which I specified and let intercom to use its 2.4.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
compile('io.intercom.android:intercom-sdk:1.1.2@aar') {
    exclude group: 'com.squareup.okhttp', module: 'okhttp'
  }
```

However pay attention. If the library uses methods that are not present in the 2.2.0 release, it will fail.

Comment: Thanks. That is what I was worried about, because I already tried that and as you said it fails. Could you please explain what would happen if I remove transitive?

Comment: As I know, when you add the @aar annotation, to have dependence transitive ( (i.e., dependencies of dependencies), you should add "transitive=true".

Comment: Flagging that nowadays you need to use group id: `com.squareup.okhttp3`

Answer (score 3):

You should define a resolution strategy to set a specific version. This will guarantee you will get the correct version you wish no matter what the transitive dependency versions are:

```
allProjects {
   configurations.all {
       resolutionStrategy {
           eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
               if (details.requested.name == 'okhttp') {
                   details.useTarget('com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.2.0')
               }
            }
        }
     }
  }
```

In newer versions of Gradle you can use:

```
allProjects {
   configurations.all {
       resolutionStrategy.force 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.2.0'
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you. But won't that force my intercom dependency to use 2.2.0 as well? Or will intercom continue using 2.4.0?

Comment: You can only have one version of the jar in a dependency configuration. If you want two or more version, you will need to put them in a separate dependency, combine the dependencies for your output. You will also need to make sure the different libs are loaded in a unique classloade at run time.